# Not able to toggle on onclick event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a tree component and am able to get the tree to display....but now I want to toggle based on user click....but am not able to figure out how to do it. The "setState" method is not part of the this....this is undefined.....Could someone please explain how can this be done. Here's the Code :

```
export function TreeComponent(props){

var instance = Object.create(React.Component.prototype)

instance.props = props;   

instance.render = function(){
    return <ul>
            <Tree data={props.data} />
            </ul>
}

return instance;


function Tree(props){

    if (!props.data.children){
        return (
                <li>
                <LeafNode data={props.data}/>                
                </li>
        )
    }

    return  (            
            <li><LeafNode data={props.data}/>
            <ul>{
                props.data.children.map(function(child){
                    return <Tree data={child} />
                })
            }
        </ul></li>
    )

    function LeafNode(props){

        function toggle(){

            props.data.showChildren = !props.data.showChildren;
            this.setState();/* <----------NOT WORKING */
        }

        var toggleImg = "";

        if (props.data.children){
            toggleImg = props.data.showChildren  ?"./images/colapse.png":"./images/expand.png"; 
        }            
        return (
                <div>
                <span className="toggle" onClick={toggle} >
                <img width="9" height="9" src={toggleImg} />
                </span>
                <a href="">{props.data.name}</a>
                </div>
        )
    }   
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Why you didn't use class based component? It is easier to create any component using class based component pattern and you can use state and lifecycle methods to add any kind of functionality to the components you want to create.

Comment: because i hate class keyword.....is it possible to do without switching to class keyword based syntax?

Comment: everyone writes a stateful component using es6 class now a days. If you write it using "class" keyword way many people will come and try to solve your problem

Comment: hi, i managed to get it working, it is here in case anybody interested : [ https://github.com/harsh-a1/react-tree-component/blob/master/components/app.js ]